# Biblatex: Wrong abbreviations of names

Tags: biblatex

I've noticed something strange in the way biblatex abbreviates certain names.
It appears to ignore parts of hyphenated names if they are shorter than three
characters.  For example, `Yi-feng Wang` becomes "f. Wang" instead of "Y.-f.
Wang".  `Yix-feng Wang` yields the expected result, however.

[image: Example screenshot]

I hope you'll be able to reproduce this with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle-ticomp,
    autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{lib.bib}
    @article{orig,
        author     = {Wang, Yi-feng and Wang, Zhi-yuan},
    }
    @article{test,
        author     = {Wang, Yix-feng and Wang, Zhi-yuan},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
\begin{document}
Test with actual author names \autocite{orig}.
Test with changed author name (note the extra letter x) \autocite{test}.
\end{document}
```

If this is a bug and not a mistake on my part I would like to get some ideas
for workarounds.  What I've come up with so far is the following:

```
    @article{workaround,
        author     = {Wang, Yi{-}feng and Wang, {Zhi-yuan}},
    }
```

I don't mind that the names get abbreviated with a single letter this way, ie.,
"Y. Wang and Z. Wang".  Maybe it's even better this way.

However, note the different methods of escaping I had to use in the names to
make it work.  I would have to be extremely careful when going through my
database to make these changes.  Can someone explain why any of this happens?

I use Texlive 2012, biblatex 0.9a and biber 0.9.9.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Your texlive is rather old, the first thing to do would be to update your installation.

Comment: Just an update to @AndrewSwanns somment, in most cases you will have to reinstall TeX Live in a newer version. It is not possible/recommended in general to update from one TL installation to another.

Comment: I had to add `uniquename=init` to the options to force the first name to use initials but then it worked fine with a current biblatex and biber.

Comment: In order to hide the hyphen, that normally denotes a compound name, you want `Wang, {Zhi-yuan}`, which is easier than `Zhi{-}yuan`.

Comment: I tried compiling things in a VM with a more recent distribution and it did
solve the problem.  I was hoping to not have to upgrade my tools so close to
a deadline but it'll have to do.

So, I assume my problem was caused by a bug in biblatex that has already been
fixed.  Thanks for your time, everybody.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by an outdated version of the software (see comment above).